# twitteR how to search for two hashtags

Tags: r, twitter, hashtag

enter code hereIs it possible to look for two different hastags in one `searchTwitter` command?

Example

```
my_h <-  as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())
my_h <- strptime(my_h, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "CET")

hrs <- function(u) {
  x <- u * 3600
  return(x)
}
my_h <- my_h - hrs(24)
my_h <- data.frame(day = strptime(my_h, "%Y-%m-%d", tz = ""))
```

I want to look for hastags `#dn` and `#park`
I can do it separately as below

```
tweets<-twListToDF(searchTwitter("#dn", n=5000, since = as.character(my_h$day)))
write.table(tweets, "all_dn_tweets.csv", row.names = F, append = T, sep = ";", col.names = F)

tweets<-twListToDF(searchTwitter("#park", n=5000, since = as.character(my_h$day)))
write.table(tweets, "all_park_tweets.csv", row.names = F, append = T, sep = ";", col.names = F)
```

The question is if these two can be squeezed into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
hashtags <- c("#metallica", "#slayer")
needle <- paste(hashtags, collapse = " OR ")
tweets <- searchTwitter(needle, n = 10)
df <- twListToDF(tweets)
for (hashtag in hashtags) {
  write.csv(df[grep(hashtag, tolower(df$text), fixed = TRUE), ], paste0(hashtag, ".csv"))
}
```

Using `tolower` on tweets may need some error handling - you'll find plenty of infos on that on the web.

Comment: It is what I wanted, I couldn't reproduce the loop but this was not the part of the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684179/how-to-search-for-multiple-words-in-the-same-string-using-r) more elegant. For the present case it basically is

```
hashtags <- '#metallica + #slayer'
tweets <- searchTwitter(hashtags, n = 10, lang = 'en', retryOnRateLimit = 100) 
tweetsDF <- twListToDF(tweets)
```