# How to search for multiple words in the same string using R

Tags: r, tweets

I'm trying to extract tweets that contains 2-3 words in the same tweet.

Below is my code where I'm extracting tweets that matches a particular word. But I need to extract tweets that matches multiple words in the same tweet.

```
search.string <- "#DeltaAirlines"
no.of.tweets<-1500
tweets <- unique(searchTwitter(search.string, n=no.of.tweets, lang="en"))
```

I've tried using AND in the search.string function but its returning me an empty list even though there are tweets that contain those 2-3 words.

Comment: I guess it works just like with most search engines: put the required keywords in quotes... `search.string <- '"#DeltaAirlines" "sucks"'`.

Comment: Is the the `+` operator what you're looking for?  See `?searchTwitter`.  One of the examples there is `searchTwitter('world cup+brazil', resultType="popular", n=15)`

Comment: Both worked. I guess I should check the documentation first before posting questions here. Thanks guys!